# Send mail with nodemailer using react js

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

I'm trying to send mail with nodemailer from my page .

I'm using React js for the frond end .

When I'm trying to run the server with `npm run dev`  I got this message

```
npm run server

npm run client exited with code -4058
```

I can't understand the code `-4058` what does it mean .

Comment: nodemailer is a nodejs module. Not sure if it runs on the browser. It might make use of a Nodejs dependency not supported on the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use nodemailer in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630543/can-i-use-nodemailer-in-browser)

Comment: no I already have the server side and I used express

Answer (score 0):

**NO**. You cant send mail using `nodemailer` via react first it is nodejs module work at server side not on the browser.

You can either `mailto` email-link

```
<a href="mailto:nowhere@mozilla.org">Send email to nowhere</a>
```

Or as you mentioned make `REST API` call to your express using data to send email and send email from there.